# Link_to to update attribute in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a link to update a resource, without using an HTML form.

I have a Kanban board listing projects grouped by their status. Via the click of a button I want to update the status of a project moving them to the next list. This should happen on the workflows index: /tenants/{id}/workflows

**Problem**
The button_to or link_to seems to be feasible avoiding a form, but I don't know which route and params to use in the index.html.erb. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Routes**

```rb
resources :tenants do
  resources :members
  resources :projects
  resources :workflows
end
```

**Workflows/index.html.erb**

```html
<%- model_class = Project -%>
  <% @projects.where(tenant_id: @tenant.id, :status => "Nominated").each do |project| %>

    <%= project.title %>
    <%= button_to "Update", XXXX, method: :put, params: { status: "In Progress" } %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: According to your nested routes, try to change "XXX" with `tenant_project_path(project.tenant, project)`

Comment: I assume, the your `update` action of `WorkflowsController` would be taking care of changing status. If that's the case then as per you routes setting and expected url, replace `XXXX` with `tenant_worflow_path`

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to **tenant_workflows_path(tenant_id: @tenant.id)**  However, now **No route matches [PUT] "/tenants/2/workflows"**. How would I define this, and secondly, how do I add **project.title** as the current title to the params as I also get a missing parameter error?